# ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 Tutorials

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am new to ASP.NET AJAX. Can anybody tell me good resource for the same? I have googled but was unable to find good tutorials to learn basic and advanced use of ASP.NET AJAX 4.0.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/

Comment: You have googled? Really? I wonder how you managed to find *nothing*...

Answer (score 0):

There's probably not a whole lot of resources for 4.0 yet because it's not released... it's still in Preview 3. Documentation doesn't kick into high gear until the API has been nailed down, usually by RC1. Preview documentation is [available here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/ajax/templates/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

They just updated the preview release to include client documentation, a detailed readme (with good explainations and examples of the new features), and a set of samples for the new client templates:

[ASP.NET AJAX 4.0 Preview 4 on CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24645)